# Alterar a cor do texto de um iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

É possível mudar a cor do texto de um `iframe`?

```
<div class="col-md-10 padding" style="background-color:white;">                    
    <iframe height="500" scrolling="no" name="Resultado" src="rastreamento.aspx?post=JT720196464BR"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Por medida de segurança, não, salvo de você integrá-los (neste caso, você terá que poder alterar o código fonte do site que está carregando via `iframe`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função do iframe é abrir um documento externo em sua página web, seja ele localhost ou externo. Algumas soluções em javascript podem ajudar a fazer o que você quer, mas apenas se for um documento no mesmo servidor.

Portanto, a resposta é não, pois é a mesma coisa que você querer editar um facebook que não é seu, já pensou?!.

Mas, você pode criar uma cópia da página externa no seu servidor usando PHP:

```
file_get_contents(/* string: url da página */)
```

E aplicar os estilos CSS que quiser na string retornada, podendo criar até uma "versão" da página original no seu servidor, com seus próprios estilos e scripts.